# WP7 IsolatedStorageFileStream Error "Operation not permitted on IsolatedStorageFileStream"

Tags: c#, xna, text-files, isolatedstorage, isolatedstoragefile

I'm trying to open a txt file that's saved as content in my app, however I run into the error shown in the thread's title. Here's the line of code giving me trouble:
`var readStream = new IsolatedStorageFileStream(mapFileName, FileMode.Open, store);`

which is used when a the method
`map.loadMap(string mapFileName)`
is called.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**EDIT**

I've created a new method to read in the text file using an IsolatedStorageFile and IsolatedFileStream however I'm completely clueless on how I would go about reading in the data to a 2D int array, using my old parsing code and a screenshot of my map01.txt for reference could anyone suggest a way of going about this as I have not found any relevant documentation on-line:

[image: map01.txt]

```
        int x = 0, y = 0;
        var store = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();
        var readStream = new IsolatedStorageFileStream(mapFileName, FileMode.Open, store);
        var stream = new StreamReader(readStream);

        do
        {
            string line = stream.ReadLine();
            string[] numbers = line.Split(',');

            foreach (string e in numbers)
            {
                int tile = int.Parse(e);
                this.tileID[x,y] = tile;

                x++;
            }
            y++;
        }
        while (!stream.EndOfStream);`
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't use IsolatedStorage for project files, they are for files that are stored in the cache/appdata, you actually read them like a normal file.

Go to: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb199073.aspx

To learn how to open/read/save files.

Comment: Thanks I'll go check it out, so it's definitely possible to use txt files with WP7? I would really hate to have to learn XML for something as simple as a tile map

Comment: Yes text files are supported, and any file type that can be converted and reconverted to a byte[] stream.

Comment: Hey Rob, thank you for your help so far, could you possibly have a look at my edit and see if you could help me parse my IsolatedStorageFileStream into a 2D array, I've yet to find any documentation on-line about parsing it to a 2D int array

Comment: @TotalJargon Try debugging it and go line by line.  http://www.visualstudiotutor.com/2010/02/visual-studio-debugging-tutorial-basics/
You can then see the individual values and see if they work.  Also I think StringReader or one of those objects that deal with reading have an option to just put the file directly in the Create() static method.

Comment: Ok I think that I've got my code correct now although I'm error checking to make sure that the file exists and it's always returning nothing, meaning that there's an error in how I'm writing the string for the file path and name, right now I write it as "Maps\\map01.txt" and it's physical position in the project folder is: "Text to Tile Test EngineContent\Maps\map01.txt" it's sucks with programming how you have to be dead on or it wont work xD